# Provide an example of a locally connected Hausdorff space not consisting of a single point.

Tags: general-topology

Can someone provide an example of a locally connected Hausdorff space not consisting of a single point?

Comment: $\Bbb R$. $[0,1]$, if you want it to be compact.

Comment: i guess i'm having trouble of what can and what cannot be interpreted as a point.

Comment: Both of the examples that I gave have $2^\omega=\mathfrak{c}$ points. The one-point space is just a singleton set $\{x\}$ and the open sets $\varnothing$ and $\{x\}$.

Comment: "Not consisting of a single point" means the space itself is not a single point, not that it doesn't have points.

Comment: yes, i assumed it could't contain any. sorry. thank you**

Comment: Hi @BrianM.Scott, I am trying to understand your commend. What is $\mathbb{R}.[0,1]$?

Comment: @WishingFish ${\Bbb R}$ is the space of real numbers. A second example given by Brian, which is compact, is the closed interval $[0,1]$ which is defined as the set of reals $x$ satisfying $0\le x\le 1$, with the subspace topology.

Comment: Oh that's what the very abbreviated linguist meant! Thank you @anon! I was just wondering where have you been.....

Comment: @WishingFish: As anon said, two separate examples. One example is $\Bbb R$. If you want a compact example, you can use $[0,1]$ instead.

Comment: Yes, got it. Glad to see your nice answer, thanks @BrianM.Scott

Comment: @WishingFish: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is true that in English "not consisting of a single X" could be interpreted as *not having any Xs*.

However, here we mean the space is not itself a single point (see Brian's comment about the one-point space). It does not mean the space doesn't have any points!

Comment: Fun, accurate, and angry answer. Like it.